Cheap way of estimating $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4x}{x^4}\operatorname dx$

Let $I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^4x}{x^4}\operatorname dx$, find the integer part of $10I$.

In fact, it is possible to show that $I=\frac\pi3$. But I think the process is too technical. Since the problem only asks for $10I$, I am wondering if there is a cheaper way of solving it by only giving an estimation of $I$.
I tried methods like finding the Taylor series of $\sin^4x$, or using the Páde approximate of it. But then the integral diverges.

If you want to estimate an integral like this, it helps to observe that the integrand converges to zero pretty quickly. So you can separately try to estimate the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ and bound the integral from $\pi$ to $\infty$, for example. For the tail bound, the very cheap estimate $|\sin^4 x| \le 1$ will probably be good enough, but you can get a better estimate. One cute way is to observe that it suffices to estimate the integral from $\pi$ to $2\pi$, because it's an alternating series.

Using "Lobachevsky integral formula":
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin ^4(x) f(x)}{x^4} \, dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} f(t) \, dt-\frac{2}{3}
   \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin ^2(t) f(t) \, dt$$
We have:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} 1 \, dt-\frac{2}{3} \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin ^2(t) \, dt=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{2
   \pi }{3\ 4}=\frac{\pi }{3}
$$

Would you by chance know who is  $1.05033948930067537980228710158997279210674488906621322299631811396272
6354177905679387917866803058271$ ? Thanks & cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici. Sorry AskConstans can't find.

Thanks in any manner, Mariusz ! Cheers

Integration by parts
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin ^4 x}{x^4} d x=-\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{+\infty} \sin ^4 x d\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \\
& =-\left[\frac{\sin ^4 x}{3 x^3}\right]_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{4\sin ^3 x \cos x}{x^3} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Noting that $$
\begin{aligned}
& \sin ^3 x \cos x=\frac{1-\cos 2 x}{2} \cdot \frac{\sin 2 x}{2}  =\frac {2 \sin 2 x-\sin 4 x}{8} ,\\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
we have $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\frac{1}{12} \int_0^{+\infty}(2 \sin 2 x-\sin 4 x) d\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{12} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{4 \cos 2 x-4 \cos 4 x}{x^2} d x \\
& =-\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{+\infty}(\cos 2 x-\cos 4 x) d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{-2 \sin 2 x+4 \sin 4 x}{x} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{3}\left(-2 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 2 x}{x} d x+4 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin 4 x}{x} d x\right)\\
& =\frac{\pi}{3} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Note:
The last answer that $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin (k x)}{x} d x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Wish it helps.

Students will appreciate is more, I would have done this only. +1

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^1e^{itx}dt.$$ $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_R e^{ixt}(1-\frac{|t|}{2})_+dt$$
(the tent function for the density of the sum of two iid uniform rv).
The density $f(t)$ of the sum of 4 iid uniform rv on $(-1,1)$ is the convolution of two tent functions $$f(t)=\int_R (1-\frac{|s|}{2})_+(1-\frac{|t-s|}{2})_+ds\ (*)$$ its characteristic function is $\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}$ and from the inversion formula$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_Re^{-ixt}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}dx\ \ (**).$$ Doing $t=0$ in (*) and (**) we get the result $\pi/3.$
